# Getting this conditional formatting formula to work with COLUMNS and not ROWS?

Tags: google-sheets, gs-conditional-formatting

I have a formula which when applied to conditional formatting, changes 2 rows at a time, then leaves 2, then changes 2, then leaves 2 - and so on. The formula is:

```
=MOD(INT((ROW(1:1)-1)/2),2)=0`
```

Can anybody tell me how I would convert this to work with columns instead of rows?

I've tried changing the word `ROW` to `COLUMN` but it isn't working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try:

```
=MOD(INT((COLUMN(A:A)-1)/2),2)=0
```